# Passive Joint Problem

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,
I want to simulate the passive joint(sping-damper) using in my model. But what i found in the joint setting is just `<damping>` tag, without stiffness tag as expected.
Any suggest to that idea?
Thank so much!

Here my joint:

```
<joint type='revolute' name='Joint'>
 <pose>0 0.0 0.0 0 0.0 0</pose>
 <child>LowerSg</child>
 <parent>UpperSg</parent>
 <axis>
  <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
      <dynamics>
       <damping>0.0000</damping>
       <friction>0.0000</friction>
      </dynamics>
 </axis>
</joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6770/passive-joint-problem/) by [RoboTN](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/863/robotn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We added spring stiffness tags to gazebo 3.1 in [pull request 1117](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1117). See the changes to the [spring_damper_test.world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1117/sdf-tags-for-joint-spring-stiffness-and/diff#chg-test/worlds/spring_damper_test.world) for an example of the syntax.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0